# Compare JavaScript object against "default" version?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Is there a way in JavaScript to check if an object fits a sort of "template" without just checking each value individually?

i.e. I am loading a config.json file in a node.js app which I need to make sure has all of the necessary config options and fill with defaults for those that aren't present. I would prefer to just have a "default" config object and compare the loaded object against it and fill the missing data with the data from the default rather than comparing each individual key.

Comment: Use a loop over all keys. There's no way out. You can also use `Object.assign`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use `Object.assign` to override defaults. this is the native solution for this problem, before that people used underscore's "mixin" and jquery's "extend" to get this behavior.

## Syntax

> Object.assign(target, ...sources)

## Example

```
var defaults = {
   name: defaultName
}

function Factory(options={}) {
  this.settings = Object.assign({}, defaults, options);
}
Factory.prototype.getName = function() {
   return this.settings.name;
}

var myFactory = new Factory({name: "myFactory"});
myFactory.getName(); //returns "myFactory"
```

Comment: `opts = Object.assign({}, defaults, options);` is probably a bit better so that you don't override your defaults globally.

Comment: @zzzzBov It is worth mentioning that you need to be careful when using  `Object.assign()` because it doesn't do a deep copy / clone. So it is not the same behavior of `jQuery.extend(true, {}, defaults, options)`.

Comment: @DiegoZoracKy, and likewise you need to be careful with `jQuery.extend` because it does a deep copy, which also might not be what you want.

Comment: @zzzzBov yeap! 